# How to get SplineWithBarriers to work in C#

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, raster, c#, geoprocessing

I have been having fits trying to get SplineWithBarriers to work but to no avail.

My environment:
Windows 7 64 bit
Visual Studio 2010 Team Edition
ArcMap
Release Version 10.0
Product Version: 10.0.2.3200
Spatial Analyst License

Should also mention this is C# code.

I have tried all I can think of and everything looks correct except I continue to get an "E_FAIL" exception whenever it is run. I am hoping someone on this forum has done this and is able to point out my problems. Thanks for any and all help.

Following is my full method.

private void DoSplineWithBarriers()
{ 
    SplineWithBarriers swb = new SplineWithBarriers();

```
IWorkspaceFactory wksFact;
IFeatureWorkspace featWks;
IFeatureClass inPtsFC;
IGeoFeatureLayer geoFeatLyr;

wksFact = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass(); 
featWks = wksFact.OpenFromFile("C:\\Workarea\\swb", 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;

inPtsFC = featWks.OpenFeatureClass("pointsFeature");
geoFeatLyr = new FeatureLayerClass();
geoFeatLyr.Name = inPtsFC.AliasName;
geoFeatLyr.FeatureClass = inPtsFC;

featWks = wksFact.OpenFromFile("C:\\Workarea\\swb", 0) as
IFeatureWorkspace;

IFeatureClass barriers;
barriers = featWks.OpenFeatureClass("barrierFeature");

Raster outPutRas = new Raster();

swb.Input_point_features = (object)inPtsFC;
swb.Z_value_field = (object)"DEPTH";
swb.Output_raster = (object)outPutRas;
swb.Input_barrier_features = (object)barriers;
swb.Output_cell_size = (object)0;
swb.Smoothing_Factor = 0.0;
swb.ToolboxDirectory = "C:\\Program Files
                        (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.0\\ArcToolbox\\Toolboxes";

Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
gp.AddOutputsToMap = false;

try
{
    gp.Execute(swb, null);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    string msg = "";
    msg = String.Format("Exception creating spline: {0}\r\nStack trace:\r\n{1}",
    ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
}
```

}